# Bootstrap4 button with text and icons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to put some space between the explore text and font-awesome icon by using bootstrap4

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and post the code you've attempted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

insert `&nbsp;` to add more spaces.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-adjust"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Explore</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the way I'm using for buttons:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-close mr-1"></i> Primary</button>
```

Use the default spacing class to add space as you needed.

Thank you.